# Is there a standard way of linking to a tweet using solely the ID?

Tags: twitter, oembed, twitter-search

I have a database of Tweet IDs, acquired from `search/tweets`, that I need to eventually convert to oEmbed format. In order to do this, the first step is to get a Tweet's URL. How can I link to a tweet using only the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `statuses/oembed` call. As the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) states, you don't need the *full* url, you can also use just the tweet ID.

Example: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id=507185938620219395

From Twitter's blog: https://blog.twitter.com/2014/pro-tip-for-embedding-tweets-use-the-oembed-api-endpoint

Comment: Great - thanks. I was tearing my hair out attempting to find out why `statuses/oembed` was returning a 34 error. It turns out my IDs were the `bigint` versions - not `id_str`. 